# Leaving US temporarily to pursue a Ph.D. what to do with my assets?

Tags: 401k, money-transfer, immigration

I am currently on an H1b working as a software engineer in the US. I am applying to a lot of Ph.D. positions in Europe & Asia. I have about 350k USD in Index funds(100k+ profits) and 150k USD in my 401k.

So together I have around half a million dollars in funds. I am a citizen of India. Is there a way I can continue to hold my securities when I am studying? My employer is going to recruit me back and I will come back to America after finishing my studies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure you're coming back, I don't why you can't leave it in the US.

Two suggestions would be to:

1. Roll the 401(k) into an IRA at the same brokerage where you keep the $350K, and
2. talk to a co-worker who won't be leaving the States about using their **address** (your name, their address) for the accounts.

Comment: By same company do you mean, the same brokerage company where I am holding my index funds?

Comment: @Aditya yes; I clarified that.